# Error en la consulta sql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo la siguiente tabla y quiero hacer un registro de ciertos valores desde php pero al intentar ingresar me dice que hay un error a la hra de insertar los datos[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y tengo el siguiente codigo para ingresar esos datos a la base

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['add_sale']))
 {
  $req_fields = array('codd','nro','razon','codt', 'date', 'codst', 'user', 'desc', 'dep', 'rif');
  validate_fields($req_fields);
  if(empty($errors))
 {
    $codj  = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['codd']));
     $ord  = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['nro']));
   $razon  = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['razon']));
   $tipo  = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['codt']));
  $date  = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['date']));
$st  = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['codst']));
$user  = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['user']));
$desc  = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['desc']));
$dep  = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['dep']));
$rif  = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['rif']));
$sql  = "INSERT INTO ordenes (";
$sql .= " date, cod_dep, nro_orden, departamento_name, rif_prov, razon_social ,tipo_orden ,status ,descripcion, usuario_r";
$sql .= ") VALUES (";
$sql .= "'{$date}','{$codj}','{$ord}','{$dep}','{$rif}','{$razon}','{$tipo}','{$st}','{$desc}','{$user}'";
$sql .= ")";

if($db->query($sql) or die (mysql_error()))
{
  $session->msg('s',"Venta agregada ");
  redirect('sales.php', false);
} else {
    $session->msg('d','Lo siento, registro falló.');
    redirect('sales.php', false);
}
   } else {
$session->msg("d", $errors);
redirect('sales.php',false);
 }
}

 ?>
```

Pueder ser algun error con los tipos de datos que ingreso o el array?

Comment: ¿puedes poner el error que te lanza? También te recomiendo imprimir con un `echo $sql;` para ver como se monta el Insert.

Comment: Que tiene que ver la etiqueta Java si lo que usas es PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en la siguiente parte de tu consulta:

```
$sql .= "'{$date}','{$codj}','{$ord}','{$dep}','{$rif}','{$razon}','{$tipo}','{$st}','{$desc}','{$user}'";
```

Tienes las variables $tipo y $st entre comillas simples como si fuera un varchar, pero en la tabla de la base de datos (que corresponde a tipo_orden y status), estos campos son de tipo integer. Te sugiero quitar esas comillas y probar.

```
$sql .= "'{$date}','{$codj}','{$ord}','{$dep}','{$rif}','{$razon}',{$tipo},{$st},'{$desc}','{$user}'";
```

Espero te funcione, quedo atento.